# how to render html code with style in ckeditor5 body? but I don't want paste code in body but render it from code level in angular 15

Tags: javascript, typescript, ckeditor5, angular15, ckeditor5-plugin

I want to render html code in Ckeditor5 body with css on it. but dont want to copy-paste snippent in body and then render it. I want to render it from code level, where i can write code in my angular 15 project and then render it by click of button/plugin.

I tried some methods of it, but it only provided me the way by pasting the html code in body & then it will render it.